# Jquery Custom Progress Bars not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a question on how to make this code animate correctly. I'm trying to make a progress bar that animates based on a small algorithm I built, but it's not animating. Here's my code:

```
function WidthGenerator() {
"use strict";
var question = prompt("Enter number of hours worked:", "Enter here");
if (isNaN(Number(question)) === false) {
    var generateMultiplier = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
    alert(generateMultiplier);
    var newWidth = question * generateMultiplier;
    alert(newWidth);
    return newWidth;
} else {
    question = prompt("That is not a number; Enter the number of hours worked.", "Enter here");
}
}

$(document).ready(function () {
"use strict";
$('#Progress-Button').click(function () {
    var animateWidth = WidthGenerator();
    var widthCheck = $('#Progress-Bar').css('width');
    if (widthCheck < animateWidth) {
        $('#Progress-Bar').animate({
            width: '+=1%'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('#Progress-Bar').stop();
    }
});
});
```

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to make it increase every time the button is triggered. Example: User generates 20% of progress bar filled, then runs the generator again and generates an additional 30%. How would I make it so the progress bar shows 50%?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you link a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so your code can be played with?

Comment: Here you go! :D https://jsfiddle.net/jo1t7fnL/

Comment: Have a look at the line 20 in your javascript. You are comparing the width of the #Progress-Bar, which is 0px, with the integer you got from the function. Also, the animation-sequence by adding 1% seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what @Jabaluza pointed out above.

Change: `$('#Progress-Bar').css('width');`
to: `$('#Progress-Bar').outerWidth();`

Not sure if this gives you your intended result but the first is returning a string with 'px' in it, the latter is returning the number you're looking for.